# NuGet pack is ignoring assembly info

Tags: nuget-package

When I run `nuget pack MyProject.csproj` from the command line, I get the following error:

> The replacement token 'author' has no value.

I checked my AssemblyInfo, and the AssemblyCompany is specified as "AJ Richardson". I tried manually replacing `$author$` with `AJ Richardson` in my nuspec file, but then I got a slightly different error:

> The replacement token 'description' has no value.

But the `AssemblyDescription` is also specified. It seems that NuGet is not reading anything from my `AssemblyInfo`. I have verified that `AssemblyInfo` is included in my project and the build action is set to Compile.

I have made a couple of NuGet packages before and did not have any issues. The only difference between this package and my previous packages is that this one has dependencies.

For reference, here is my nuspec:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <licenseUrl>https://github.com/my/repo/blob/master/LICENSE</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>https://github.com/my/repo</projectUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>$description$</description>
    <releaseNotes>Initial release.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright AJ Richardson 2015</copyright>
    <tags></tags>
  </metadata>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.1" />
  </dependencies>
</package>
```

So my question is, why isn't NuGet reading my `AssemblyInfo`, and how do I convince it to do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the problem was that I hadn't built my project since modifying the `AssemblyInfo`. I did a rebuild and it's working now.

(As a side note, I also had the `<dependencies>` in the wrong section - it should be inside of `<metadata>` - but that was not causing the error in my question.)

Comment: What was the NuGet version that you were using? I'm having the same problem with NuGet v3.5.0 and a VS2015 project. Its not able to pick up the Author value, even though the project was rebuilt.

Comment: @EndlessSpace I can't remember exactly since this was a year and a half ago. It would have been v3.x (maybe 3.0 or 3.1?)

Comment: Also, be sure that you are building in the same configuration as `nuget pack` is using.

Comment: @EndlessSpace Same issue here. It does pick up ID, version and title from the assembly info, but not author or description.

Comment: If this answer doesn't work for you, there's a bug report and discussion on Github https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4234 @EndlessSpace

Comment: @Liven - Doesn't look like it's going to be fixed.

Answer (score 18):

I was also experiencing issues in this regard; my updates to AssemblyInfo didn't seem to be being picked up - despite me building and rebuilding, etc.

I was able to resolve the issue by explicitly telling NuGet to build (in my case in Release, with pdb symbols):

`nuget pack foo.csproj -Build -Symbols -Properties Configuration=Release`

Comment: Your answer drew to my attention a detail that I had forgotten since the last time I built a NuGet package, which was 3 years ago. Since my solution was already built, and I didn't want to create yet another build just for the package, I deduced correctly that I could omit the -Build argment, but that I needed the -Configuration switch.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, but it turns out that someone introduced a signing key, and I was referencing assemblies that didn't have a strong name.

Weird that I didn't get a different error.